# preg_replace mix and match word combinations with array

Tags: php, regex

I'm wanting to bold keywords that exist next to each other (or one word apart) from two arrays. I'm taking this approach because a huge keyword list seems to be eating up memory. This *seems* more efficient.

```
$firstarray= array('baseball','soccer','tennis');
$secondarray= array('ball','shoes','glove');
```

Example:

```
$string = She like to play soccer and baseball. But in the evening she likes to hit the tennis ball. She also just bought new tennis court shoes. Tennis court performance shoes.
```

The needles I want to find are "tennis ball" and "tennis court shoes". You'll notice that COURT isnt in the array, but its BETWEEN two keywords and i'd like to have it included. "Tennis court performance" shoes isnt a needle because two keywords are seperated by two other non-keywords.

wouldnt be a needle.

So ultimately:

```
 $string = preg_replace("#\b(?:(firstarray)\W+(?:\w+\W+){0,2}?(secondarray)\b#i", '<strong>tennis ball</strong><strong>tennis court shoes</strong>', $string);
```

1. Obviously the issue is, i'm terrible, terrible at regex. I cant find many solutions with regex that apply with combinations from a list/array of words.
2. I'm not sure how exactly i'd go about using two arrays, mix and matching, AND pass them into the haystack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
<?php
$firstarray= array('baseball','soccer','tennis');
$secondarray= array('ball','shoes','glove');
$string = 'She like to play soccer and baseball. But in the evening she likes to hit the tennis ball. She also just bought new tennis court shoes. Tennis court performance shoes.';
foreach($firstarray as $term1) {
    foreach($secondarray as $term2) {
        $string = preg_replace('~\b(' . preg_quote($term1) . '\b\s+([a-zA-Z]+\s+)?\b' . preg_quote($term2) . '\b)~', '<strong>$1</strong>', $string); 
    }
}
echo $string;
```

Output:

```
She like to play soccer and baseball. But in the evening she likes to hit the <strong>tennis ball</strong>. She also just bought new <strong>tennis court shoes</strong>. Tennis court performance shoes.
```

Test live: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e8b34064f235933b5a5805bbe420d7d44d00ee46

We loop through both arrays to go through every possible combination of terms. We run the regex on each pairing and replace it if we find a match. The `([a-zA-Z]+\s+)` is my way of finding one possible word in between the list of words. You might want to add in hyphens or any other characters you want to allow in a "word".  I define a "word" as ending with a white space.

Also this is case sensitive just noticed you had the `i` modifier. If you want to re-enable that just add that and take out the `A-Z` (`A-Z` won't hurt anything with the `i`, just redundant).

The `preg_quote` currently isn't necessary but if your terms in the future have a special regex character in it it will be necessary; better off to just include it now.

Comment: Wonderful! Works excellent with the tests/variations I tried. I added the "i" modifier to make it case insensitive (thanks for the note on that). Super awesome, kudos to you for the help.

Comment: I'll continue searching, but I have to ask because you probably could fart it out before I find it How could I have the string check for plural versions of words without having to add plural versions to the array? IE have "baseball" in the array, but it also checks for "baseballs"

s? seems to be the key, but not sure how to implement it with the preg_quote+variable there

Comment: (es|s)? seems to be the ticket

Comment: Yea, `(es|s)?` should do the trick. Depending on how large your list gets and the terms that will fail at some point, e.g. foot/feet.